# I am working on an android app that need to create a text file and write in it. I use the following code

Tags: android, android-external-storage, file-writing

I am working on an android app that need to create a text file and write in it. I use the following code:

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    writeInFile("Hello world");
}

public void writeInFile(String string) {
    String dir = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File file = new File(dir, "MyFile.txt");
    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file,true);
        //fw.append(string);
        fw.write(string);
        Toast.makeText(this, "You wrote in the file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run the app, the file is created, I can see the toast message, but nothing in written in it. I have tried fw.append and fw.write. In my manifest I have yet written the necessary permission to write on external storage. I want to write directly in the external storage of my Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 (Marshmallow), not on the SD card.

Comment: @DigitalNinja: No. External storage is not removable storage on most Android devices, for the definitions of "external storage" and "removable storage" used in conjunction with the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

First, always `close()`. You are not closing your `FileWriter`.

Second, always `flush()`. You are not flushing your `FileWriter`.

Third, even if you `flush()` and `close()`, due to the way buffered filesystems work, the bytes may not yet be written to disk. You're flushing from the Android app to the OS, but the writes to the disk may be buffered and delayed by the OS. To deal with this, I don't use `FileWriter`, but `FileOutputStream` (sometimes wrapped in an `OutputStreamWriter`), so you can call `getFd().sync()` on the `FileOutputStream` after calling `flush()` and before calling `close()`.

Fourth, you won't be able to see this file and its contents in your desktop OS file manager until it gets indexed by `MediaStore`. Either test your results using other means (e.g., `adb pull`), or use `MediaScannerConnection` and its `scanFile()` method to tell the `MediaStore` to index your newly-created file.

The following code demonstrates everything but the `MediaScannerConnection` bit:

```
  private static class SaveThread extends Thread {
    private final String text;
    private final File fileToEdit;

    SaveThread(String text, File fileToEdit) {
      this.text=text;
      this.fileToEdit=fileToEdit;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      try {
        fileToEdit.getParentFile().mkdirs();

        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(fileToEdit);

        Writer w=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));

        try {
          w.write(text);
          w.flush();
          fos.getFD().sync();
        }
        finally {
          w.close();
        }
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception writing file", e);
      }
    }
  }
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Files/FilesEditor))